What is the token for the title of a node referenced by an entity select field?
I have a webform with an Entity Select field whose machine name is topic, which references nodes.
I want to to display the title of the referenced node in a confirmation email, using a token. The closest I can get is [webform_submission:values:topic:name]. However, that token includes the numeric ID of the node, so the output looks like My Node Title (123).
What token can I use to just show the node title without the node ID?

This token 'll print the node title without nid
[webform_submission:values:topic:entity:title]

where "topic" is the field name
By using entity in the token, can further access the entity field's values
